# View.GONE vs View.INVISIBLE in updating UI from another thread

Tags: android, user-interface, view, invisible

I used `setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)` from another thread and the View disappeared, but when I use `View.GONE` the application crashes with error:

> Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its
> views.

What is the difference between `setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)` and `setVisibility(View.GONE)` when both of them are updating the `UI` thread?

```
        final Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            textView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });
```

**UPDATE**

I know the difference between `INVISIBLE` and `GONE`. I meant why is there no exception for `INVISIBLE` while it also touches the UI element in the other thread?

Comment: Both should not be used from another thread. That one worked was sheer luck.

Comment: Updates to UI elements should always be done on Main Thread.

Comment: `setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)` only make the view invisible.That view is still there just invisible,if you put a clicklistener on it it will still work if you click on that spot,but `setVisibility(View.GONE);` just makes it as if there were no view no onclick would work, if you set another view below this view then that view will simply go up becase that view is no more there

Comment: In Android UI update need to be done in MainThread. Post the crash Log.

Comment: It is interesting that I had the same question and reached yours from 2019 :))
ADM's answer seems to be right. I had the same idea but looking for confirmation.
Thanks and take care!

Answer (score 2):

From the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#INVISIBLE)

> INVISIBLE : This view is invisible, but it still takes up space for
>   layout purposes. Use with setVisibility(int) and android:visibility.
>
> GONE : This view is invisible, and it doesn't take any space for
>   layout purposes. Use with setVisibility(int) and android:visibility.

So if you use invisible flag view will be hidden, but the space that it occupies will be there and if you use gone flag view will be hidden and the space it occupies will be gone.

Also, You are changing views from thread other that main thread which is not allowed as main thread is the only thread that can interact with ui elements.

Comment: why there is no exception for INVISIBLE while it also touchs the UI element in other thread?

Answer (score 1):

You can only change the layout from the UI Thread with that said `View.INVISIBLE` does not make any changes to the structure of the views since the `View` is stil there e.g. taking space while `View.GONE` frees the used space which is a hierarchy change.

You can fix it by using [`runOnUiThread`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable)).

Answer (score 1):

Well the question seems reasonable to me in one case . If you run following code :-

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    button=findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            Log.e("thread",Thread.currentThread().getName());
        }
    }).start();
}
```

It runs without error and set visibility of `Button` to `INVISIBLE`. It will run similar for `VISIBLE` and any other operation of calling views.

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.e("thread",Thread.currentThread().getName());
            button.setText("Hi from "+Thread.currentThread().getName());

        }
    }).start();
```

This will run too .  And yeah it does prints the current thread as a new thread :- `E/thread: Thread-16`.
I think the reason for that is `View#post()` . Any operation on View should perform after it draws on the screen . In this case `View` is now drawn yet this is why the current operation will push on the message queue of Main Thread Handler. and it will run after drawing is complete(On main thread because of `View#post()`) without any error .

On other hand if you call this on some event click on button click it will throw `Exception` cause view has already been drawn and it will directly call the operation on same thread without Posting it through `Handler`.

Hope i have make it clear enough . Correct me if this theory is wrong in anyway .